# How to use dynamic types as return types in Python/mypy

Tags: python, fastapi, mypy, pydantic

I am trying to use a dynamically created type to use as return type.

The code works, but mypy throws an error.

The code snippet shows the problem in a very simplified way, but where I am using dynamic return types in my project, they have meaning (FastAPI for capturing the response structure in OpenAPI specs)

The problem I am having is getting mypy to accept the dynamic type as a valid type. It breaks with the `[valid-type]` error:

```
cpl/features/aup/api/mypy_error.py: note: In function "list_products":
cpl/features/aup/api/mypy_error.py:79: error: Variable "cpl.features.aup.api.mypy_error.PydanticProduct" is not valid as a type  [valid-type]
cpl/features/aup/api/mypy_error.py:79: note: See https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/common_issues.html#variables-vs-type-aliases
```

I have condensed the problem I am having into the snippet below:

```py
# creating class dynamically
Product = type("Product", (object, ), {})


# Use dynamic class as return type
def list_products() -> list[Product]:  # This gives [valid-type] error
    """
    List all products.

    :return: A list of products.
    """
    return [Product(), Product(), Product()]
```

Can anyone help me solve this, there must be a way to address mypy to accept this sort of typing.

**Note:** Where I am actually using this is in a FastAPI endpoint, so the actual return type structure has meaning for the generated OpenAPI spec.

Comment: There might be some tricks you can pull, but in general, no, mypy (and similar tools) will not be able to handle dynamic types like this. Are you absolutely sure you need it?

Comment: Since you’re using mypy, this is a job for a mypy plugin: https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/extending_mypy.html. See `get_dynamic_class_hook`.

Comment: @M.O. Yes I need it, I do not feel good about having to create 2 classes for each ORM, the ORM class itself and the Pydantic version of it for endpoints.

Answer (score 0):

Tools like Mypy perform static analysis on your code, meaning that they cannot analyse code where information about return types is determined at runtime.

You mentioned that your reason for generating these classes at runtime was to avoid the need to manually create many repetitive class definitions.

As such, perhaps something that could help is the `Protocol` feature, which is explained in [PEP 544](https://peps.python.org/pep-0544/). It allows you to create a class to describe the behaviour of a type, then use that class as a stand-in for the actual type.

By defining a protocol class that describes the properties and methods that the object is guaranteed to have, you could annotate your function using that protocol rather than using the type that you create dynamically.

You can also use the [`@runtime_checkable` decorator](https://peps.python.org/pep-0544/#runtime-checkable-decorator-and-narrowing-types-by-isinstance) to support type narrowing on your protocols using `isinstance`.